# How to create a class with dynamic property (Expandoobject?)

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I have a partial class named Exam. The class structure shown as below:

```
public partial class Exam 
{
    public string ID { set; get; } //default
    public string Name { set; get; } //default
}
```

After executed the store procedure, the retrieved data should contains one or more test methods as shown as following structure. I would like to put the retrieved data to dynamic object Exam. How can I create a dynamic object for object Exam and how can i bind the data to this dynamic object?

```
ID, Name, Test1, Test2, Test3....
1, Peter, Y, N, Y
1, John, N, Y, Y

public virtual ObjectResult<Exam> sp_exam()
{
    return  ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).
              ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Exam>("ConnectionEntities.sp__exam");
}
```

Comment: You do this by means of something called a dynamic proxy. Take a look at Castle.Core library for the code, and browse around the web on this topic. You could most certainly use a DynamicObject as well, just that I'm not sure how it performs compared to Castle.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK ExpandoObject is just a syntax sugar for a simple dictionary. So you can write:

```
public partial class Exam {
    public string ID { set; get; } //default

    public string Name { set; get; } //default

    public readonly Dictionary<string, object> ExtraProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

but I guess you just have a bad object model.

Comment: can you dynamic type using a simple dictionary? That's a pretty simplistic view of ExpandObject, and ignores some of its subtle features. Take a look at Clay, or ClaySharp, to see what can be done.

Comment: @code4life `can you dynamic type using a simple dictionary` - please, clarify, what does it mean